# update meta data (like view counter) by rest-api

Tags: rest-api, post-meta

i want update view counter of post in app.
i getting site data by rest-api to my app(created by ionic) ,but now i need update somethings like view counter that when a post viewed in app like site view counter increase.
i want a method that use for update value of view counter, rating or ... of post

i think i have to update meta data of post by POST intro wp api, is it true solution ? if yes, how i do ?

thanks

Comment: if the core endpoints doesn't make what you want, you can create a new endpoint https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: I don't think register a whole different endpoint is necessary, just register a new rest field: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field it allows you to define get and update callbacks where you could put your custom logic for counter, ratings, or whatever.